# SQL with nested joins and sums

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hoping someone can give me a little bit of help with a query that I'm stuck on.
Using MS-Sql server 2012

This is part of a larger query but for the purposes of my questions I'm only concerned with 4 tables: Account, user, product, productstats

And a simplified layout of each table is as follows:

```
account: id, parentaccountID, name
user: id, accountID, email
product: id, accountID
productstats: id, productID, views
```

So user links to the account table and the account table can link to itself with the parentaccountID field. Product table links to the user table and the productstats table links to the product table.

The productstats contains statistics on each product. In my example above we have how many times someone has viewed a product.

I want to get the sum of all product views under each parent account, including it's child accounts.  However, when people search for an account they can search either via account.name or user.email

so if they search by user.email, i want to include all products from that users account, and any child or parent account(s) that it's part of.

One note - the parent/child account structure is only 1 level deep. Meaning an account is either the parent or the child, it's never both. parent accounts have a null value for ParentAccountID.

```
SELECT a2.ParentAccountID, a.id, a.Name, SUM(ps.PageViews) 
FROM account a
LEFT JOIN account a2 ON a.id = a2.ParentAccountID
LEFT JOIN product p ON a.id = p.AccountID OR p.AccountID = a2.ID
LEFT JOIN ProductStatistic ps ON p.id = ps.ProductID                    
WHERE a.ame LIKE 'test'                  
GROUP BY a.id, a2.ParentAccountID, a.DealerName
```

That's a simplified version of the query - I haven't even included the user table yet since i haven't gotten it working this far yet.

The values I get back on that query are:
ParentAccountID =4, ID =4, name=test, sum=1617

When I run the following query

```
SELECT SUM(pageviews) FROM ProductStatistic WHERE ProductID IN (
SELECT id FROM product WHERE AccountID IN (4, 32, 112, 3757, 3794))
```

I get 453 back as the result - those account IDs are the parent account ID and it's 4 child accounts. I have no idea how it's getting 1617 since that's not even a multiple of 453

Comment: Remove the group by and see what rows you are getting back. This might help you debug it yourself.

Comment: If i remove the group by and select *, i get way too many records. There are 375 records in the stats table for those accounts - actually, only 2 of the accounts have products (4 and 32) but it's returning 376 records for 32 (there are only 4 records) and then 372 records for each of the other 3 child accounts. So I've obviously messed up by join on the account table. I'm not sure how to correct it though - would i need to resort to using a temp table?

Answer (score 1):

When you break up your query into some smaller parts, it will become a lot clearer.

1. First obtain the accounts involved
2. Then determine the relevant products
3. Only then join in the stats table to obtain the view counts

Have a look at this this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0649/6).

[EDIT]

Added a [new fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0649/7) that adresses your comments. Not so simple no more, but I think it does what you need.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to do that. Slight problem with your example though - it's possible for there to be multiple children to each parent. And it's also possible that when someone searches, they will return multiple accounts as we allow partial matches. And i need to group by the account ID, not the product ID since I'm trying to get the sum of all product views for each account, not for each item. And I'm not sure how to both find all relevant account ID's when they can search using either user.email or account.name AND get the correct sum without duplicates.

Comment: Ooh, then things will get a bit more involved, I will write up a new fiddle

Comment: Thanks - i will play around with the code you posted in a bit and see if this will do what i want. Thanks for taking the time to write all that. I appreciate it.